# Can I prevent Google Assistant from trying to interpret the contents of a PDF email attachment

Tags: pdf-generation, actions-on-google, email-attachments

Business sends out thousands of Utility bills as attachments to emails. Recently GMail with Google assistant  has been reading the attachment and attempts to summarize the contents of the attachment. It is however making a major error in locating the account number and presenting this as the amount owed. In the image below we see an account number 7300, with a bill due amount of $18 being presented by GMail as a due amount of $7300. This has resulted in call centers being swamped with calls from users of gmail regarding the invoice amount because they haven't opened the attachment

[image: Gmail screenshot]

Assuming that it would be impossible to get google to fix the problem, are thers any options:

- Adding tags in the email to stop google from summarizing the PDF
- Design changes within the PDF

  - The account is labeled "Account Number"
  - The actual invoice amount is labeled "Total To Pay"

That would stop this happening

Comment: Converting the [PDF to an Image Only PDF](https://www.win2pdf.com/doc/batch-convert-pdf-to-image-only-pdf.html) may prevent Google Assistant from summarizing it. If you could provide a link to a sample billing PDF, I could verify that.

Comment: + I'm guessing that I'm going to provide some processing power to post-convert these PDFs to image only. The generation of the PDFs is done backend on Linux systems and they do have imagemagick available to use and that seems to be able to do what you suggest.  
 + Would these cause clickable links in the PDF to stop working?  
 + We currently don't print any detailed information in email for privacy reasons, but if I put the total amount in the body of the email, would that stop gmail trying to guess it?

Comment: Converting to image only PDF could be processor intensive. It would cause clickable links to stop working. You'll have to test putting the total amount in the body of the email. I'm not sure if that would stop Google Assistant from trying to guess it.